# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"username"}

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Here's the method I wrote with selenium to login to my webpage:

```
def login(self, username, password):
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
```

Here's the code I have in Robot Framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           CustomSelenium2Plus.py

*** Test Cases ***
SR Create New Service
    Open Browser    https://partner.sdg.msg.lab.t-mobile.com/tpim/    Chrome
    ${webdriver}=    Get webdriver instance
    Set Driver    ${webdriver}
    Login    usrnm    pwd
    ...
    Delete Service
    Close Browser
```

`CustomSelenium2Plus.py` is a custom library I wrote that subclasses RobotFramework's Selenium2Library and is where the login method is located. The method is totally functional when I call it the first time with the `Login` Keyword. However, it throws a `NoSuchElementException` when it's called a second time within `Delete Service` Keyword's function which looks like this:

```
def delete_service(self):
    self.logout()
    self.login("usrnm", "pwd")
    ...
```

I've already checked that the frame is correct. I've also already tried having my `WebDriver` wait for the visibility of both the iframe and the username textarea, an implicit `WebDriverWait`, and a `time.sleep(30)`.

EDIT: The HTML code isn't mine and pretty ugly but here's a screencap

[image]

There are technically four iframes nested within each other but calling `driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")` any more than once throws a `NoSuchFrameException`

Comment: It would probably help if you provided the relevant HTML so we can double check and make sure nothing simple was overlooked.

Comment: login method shown above doesn't have any waits for element before performing any operation, that may be the reason of NoSuchElementException, i would guess, after logout, login page is taking time to load the elements

Comment: @SatishGupta I didn't include those lines of code but I've already tried waits in my login function. I put time.sleep(30) before and after switching frames (plus the other stuff I mentioned) just to make sure. Problem still persists; works the first time around and not the second.

Comment: @EmilyZhai you might want to try explicit wait for the elements. like new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElement(<locator>). just a guess

Comment: @SatishGupta Tried that as well both before and after the frame switch.

Comment: There is 3 iframe nested, but you are saying switching iframe more than one throwing exception Right??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yep. All of this code works as it is the first time around.

Comment: Did you tried to switching further frame using `WebDriverWait` expectedCondtions as `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iframe")`??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes I tried WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "iframe")))

Answer (score 0):

I would have guessed that repeating the line `driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")` a few times would have worked. Technically that id is not unique on the page so I would try using an index instead. From the HTML you provided, it looks like the `IFRAME` you want is the first one each time. The below will hopefully work.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
```

The first line technically isn't necessary unless you are executing code before this that dives into an `IFRAME` but I included it because you had it above.

Comment: Throws a NoSuchFrameException the first time around at one, two, and three driver.switch_to.frame(0) commands.

Comment: Something is not adding up... can you share a link to the page?

Comment: I don't have a login, do you have one that you can share?

Comment: I don't think it's a great idea to share it publicly since it's a company service and someone could easily spam it. If we could get into individual contact however I could provide you with one.